# power automate no dynamic content available

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector, power-automate-desktop, microsoft-portal

In power automate every time when I try to list a table in excel it says no dynamic content available whereas I listed the same table few days back it was working fine , I need solution for this

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: i have exactly the same issue. No idea what changed, but PA doesnt display dynamic content/columns of my list

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the best is build the flow from zero, try that. It fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that if you create **Column type Image** and you choose **Yes** in field: **Require that this column contains information** >>>> Your dynamic content in Power automate will not available.

So that just choose **No** in field: **Require that this column contains information** of Image Column type and your dynamic content will available.